# Is it safe to assume free() on string(char *) returned from a function call?

Tags: c

I'm writing a function which returns NULL terminated array of strings.

Are there examples in big projects, like Linux kernel:

- when it's safe to assume (documented/custom) to call free on returned string/array of strings?
- when it's not safe/prohibited to call free on returned string/array of strings?

I'd love to explore multiple examples and understand better best practices.

Here are requirements for function I'm writing:

```
Description
Allocates (with malloc(3)) and returns an array
of strings obtained by splitting ’s’ using the
character ’c’ as a delimiter. The array must end
with a NULL pointer.

Return value
The array of new strings resulting from the split. NULL if the allocation fails.
```

Probably it's worth to mention that function is split.

Comment: It's not safe to assume anything. Read the documentation for the functions you're using.

Comment: You might need to free every pointer in the array too, depending on what they are / how they got there. The Q is unclear though, the title is different to the body. The title says `char*`, the body says "array of strings".

Comment: @interjay, do you mean function I'm writing? My Q is about best practices, customs, examples in C world.

Comment: Let’s just truncate the title to “Is it safe to assume?” and answer it “No.” Engineering is designing solutions that **conform to specifications**. You use documentation to ensure conformance, not assumptions.

Comment: @ericpostpischil, in ideal world. In some other cases, when you have lack of information, you use common sense, best practices, customs, etc. Maybe assumption is not correct word.

Comment: @Andrei: When you have lack of information, you research, inquire, examine sources, and otherwise investigate and acquire information. Once again, the answer to the question “Is it safe to assume?” is “No.” At the very least, if one must rely on something that is not documented, one would document the reliance and test it regularly. So, instead of being merely assumed, there would be at least some test of whether the requirement were true or not.

Comment: @ericpostpischil, if I say common sense/default for strings in a project to be ok with free instead of assumption?

Comment: Andrei if the function which returns a pointer was not written by you (otherwise you would know what to do), one test you can do is *empirical*. If `free()` fails, or subsequent operations which deference the pointer fail, you were wrong. OTOH if you don't `free()` and you diagnose memory leaks, then that was wrong. But the *safe* option is not to `free()` the memory.

Comment: @weathervane, thank you. It's clear. What if I'm writing function with the specification which I just put into my question? Q updated.

Comment: It would be better to post code instead of requirements for code. _"(with `malloc(3)`)"_ probably doesn't belong in a code comment describing the function. Note that functions can't return arrays in C; they can return pointers, e.g., a pointer to an array or a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @Andrei, anything that you have allocated with `malloc()` can be freed with `free()` but nothing that hasn't can be. So you have to be careful and ensure that what you `free()` is a pointer that you got from `malloc()` (and friends)  Beware that not all functions that return a null terminated string (don't use `NULL` as it's meaning is not the same as for `'\0'`) are forcibly allocating memory, so there can be cases in which it is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no situation in which you can make reasonable assumptions *either* way for an arbitrary string/array-of-string returning API, without checking the docs. C-strings are *ugly*, so you're really talking about three possibilities:

1. The API takes a string and returns a pointer within that string. Obviously it's not allocating new strings, so no `free` needed, but you still document that it's returning a pointer within the provided string (you don't want users of `strtok` thinking it's giving them newly allocated substrings)
2. The API returns a new string, either:

   1. Allocated in static/cached storage (must be documented as it involves either explicit freeing functions to return to the cache, and/or it's inherently non-reentrant and not thread safe), or
   2. Freshly allocated (and must be freed, though not always with `free`, so you need to document that as well)

Aside from those general cases, there is no standard to rely on; if it's clearly not allocating, you document that (and the lack of `free` is implicit), but in all other cases, you've got to document what cleanup, if any, is needed on a per-function basis.

When we're discussing arrays of strings, it gets even more complicated. A string splitting function could be reasonably (for some definition of reasonably) implemented in one of three ways:

1. An eager `strtok`-like function that modifies the original string in place (replacing the delimiter with `NUL`s), and returns a freshly allocated array of pointers to the existing string, which must be `free`d, but the substrings don't need to be (and in fact, the original string must be kept alive until you're done with the array)
2. A naive solution that `malloc`s the array of pointers, as well as each substring, with discrete allocations. `free` would be enough of a pain that they'd usually supply a custom freeing function to avoid every caller reimplementing it. It has lower performance and greater memory overhead than any other solution, but it does mean you can individually `realloc` and modify the substrings, which has advantages.
3. An optimized version combining traits of #1 and #2, where a single bulk allocation contains all the substring pointers, followed by the raw data for the substrings. Like #1, only a single `free` is needed to clean up the data, and in exchange for storing extra data equal to the size of the input string (but without the multiple allocation overhead and memory fragmentation), like #2 the input string can be left unchanged, the lifetime of the input string need not be extended to match that of the substring pointers (in exchange for not being able to perform `realloc`s of the substrings).

All of those have different rules for the lifetime and mutability of the input string, which components of the return value can be modified, and how, and how you clean up when you're done. There's no single standard for which to pick, so again, you've got to document it explicitly (for case #2, you don't technically need to document the exact design if you simplify cleanup to "call this freeing function" and provide reentrancy guarantees, but if you hide those implementation details, then API consumers can't benefit from some of the unique benefits of that design, like being allowed to `realloc` and mutate the substrings).

Comment: GCC has [`__attribute__((malloc))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-malloc-function-attribute), which is useful in documenting the need to `free()` memory.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's good to know, and I'm guessing the compiler can use it (sometimes) to warn when memory would be leaked, but it's not a substitute for explicitly documenting each function.

Answer (score 2):

It is only a matter of convention and API documentation.

Let's take for example a function `split()` that receives a pointer to a null terminated array of `char` (a C string) and returns a pointer to an array of pointers to C strings, itself terminated with a null pointer.  A typical implementation in C of this function would allocate both the substrings and the array with `malloc()` or similar functions such as `calloc()` or `strdup()`.

This allows the caller to handle the array without any concern over the lifespan of any of its parts, the independence of the strings and free it with a simple loop when done with it.  It is recommended for such a function to not modify its string argument so it can be called with a string literal.

In another approach, one could split the string with `strtok()`, which modifies it, allocate the array, but make its entry point to the original string, using the pointers returned by `strtok()`.  Note that it is difficult to determine the number of entries with this approach so `realloc()` may come into play to reallocate the array as it needs more elements, a tricky and error prone method. The function would have a similar prototype but different semantics and impose different constraints on the caller and the arguments. (this approach is for illustration only. `strtok()` has many drawbacks and `realloc()` is easy to misuse).

In yet another approach, both the strings and the array could be allocated in the same block of memory, allowing for the argument string to stay unchanged and making the array lifespan different from the arguments'.  This seems to be your choice. Constructing the array is more work, but freeing the array is much simpler.  Note however that this approach imposes an extra constraint on the programmer: they can change the array entries as long as they use other entries or possibly string literals, which may or may not be flexible enough for the callers' purposes.

Whether you decide for one approach or another is a matter of choice and circumstances, but the choice you make should be consistent and documented.  It is also less error prone in a larger program for different functions with similar requirements to use similar conventions.

If you have a large project handling many variable strings, I would recommend you allocate all of them and not share them.  This may be a little wasteful in terms of memory and processing time, but is simple, flexible and consistent. Use `strdup()` and `strndup()` to make copies, these functions will soon finally be included in the C Standard, have been available on POSIX systems for decades and are easy to add where not available.

Where to free the strings is a tricky question: you should free a string where the place that refers to it is changed to refer to another string, itself allocated specifically or `NULL`.  But if you implement for example a string concatenating function, whether it frees its argument strings or not is a design decision that will impact how it is called: if it frees its arguments, you will end up allocating copies for any arguments that are not a intermediary results. If conversely you do not free the arguments and make them `const char *`, you may have to keep pointers to intermediary results to free them afterwards.  I would tend to use this latter approach as it is more flexible and allows for passing string literals.  Again these choices must be consistent and documented.

Comment: "It is idiomatic in C for this function to allocate both the substrings and the array with `malloc()` or similar functions such as `calloc()` or `strdup()`." - Of course, even that has caveats. The naive solution `malloc`s the array of pointers and each substring individually, and freeing would be enough of a pain that they'd usually supply a custom freeing function to avoid every caller reimplementing it. An optimized solution might return a single bulk allocation that is subdivided into the array of pointers in front, followed by the split string data, and can be freed with a single `free`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: of course many other solutions are possible depending on various factors. Allocating each string separately allows for further processing where some of all of these strings are modified or replaced.  I should write "A typical implementation for this function  would..."

Comment: @shadowranger, that is exactly my case. I do return contiguous memory where pointers and strings they point to are all located. One free on them is enough.

Comment: @Andrei: Yep. And since either design is perfectly reasonable, no matter which way you go, you need to document the cleanup explicitly.

Comment: @chqrlie, got it! I like both explanations by you and shadowranger. Are there big projects with extensive use of strings with default assumption (i.e. common sense across a project): strings are ok to free if not saying opposite? Or vice versa: strings are not ok to free if not said opposite?

Comment: @Andrei: I amended the answer with 3 different approaches including yours... They all have advantages and drawbacks, the choice is yours but it must be consistent and documented.

Comment: @chqrlie: Hah, I was editing my answer to describe those exact three approaches myself, because I realized I hadn't properly addressed array-of-strings cases. :-) The answer is the same (you have to document on a per-function basis), but it's helpful to show *why* there's no single reasonable assumption to be made.

Comment: @Andrei: The closest thing I can come up with where there are implicit rules like that is rather higher level than strings. CPython's APIs which return `PyObject*` are implicitly assumed to return new/owned references to an object which must be released (decref-ed) when ownership is no longer needed to avoid a leak, with the exceptions carefully calling out when it returns a new *borrowed* reference. C string APIs, in my experience, don't favor one side or another enough for assumptions of that sort.